# Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' Variable Error

Tags: string, variables, swift2, swift3

Hello i have array and i want to explode 1 item into it and i want to check if variable not null or null and gives me that error

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String' Variable Error

My codes here.

```
 var myStringArrctakesf = itemListcomming.components(separatedBy: ",")

    if let commingtel = myStringArrctakesf[11] { 

 //notnull       
    } else {

//null
    }
```

I want if myStringArrctakesf[11] is null dont crash app and if not null show variable.

Thanks

Comment: An index based subscription returns the (non-optional) item at given index or raises an "Out of range" exception. That's the same behavior as in Objective-C. It will never be `nil` – unlike the key based subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`components(separatedBy: )` never contain `nil` in any of its element. Perhaps what you want is to check the `myStringArrctakesf` has at least 12 elements?

```
if myStringArrctakesf.count >= 12 {
    let comingtel = myStringArrctakesf[11]
} else {
    // Array didn't have enough components
}
```

Comment: says me "  'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion "